# Trivialization of a fibration after a base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $E\to B$ be a locally trivial fibration of curves of genus >1 (everyhting is compact and over $\mathbb{C}$). I read that this fibration becomes trivial "after a finite unramified base change". Could anyone explain what does it mean, i.e. what is the exact construction?

Comment: It becomes trivial after you perform a base change by the finite cover of symplectic bases for the $3$-torsion of your Abelian scheme.

Comment: You glue such a bundle together by transition maps: automorphisms of the fiber. But the automorphism group is finite. So after a suitable cover, you are gluing together by the identity automorphism.